# Floated elements with %-based width and px-based borders: What is the best way to avoid the line break?

Tags: css

I have an issue that terrorizes me in my sleep, unrelentingly . If you have an attainable solution and care to share it, please do; I'd like to have a normal night of sleep again.

On my latest project, there are multiple times when I will need to have 4 or 5 elements floated next to one another. Each element must be sized using percentages (%) but must also have `border-right: 1px solid #000`.

Once upon a time, I would normally size each element with percentages, then create a child element that would have all of the styling properties that the parent probably should have had, including the `border-right`. This solution isn't ideal, however, because it involves a lot of unnecessary markup.

A co-worker then directed me to another solution. When an element has a width that is sized using %s, and also needs to have `border-right: 1px solid #000`, apply `margin-right: -1px` as an offset. And while it works, it created another issue for me (which is why we're here, together, in union).

When zooming out in any of the major browsers (ctrl mousescroll, ctrl -), the floated elements that have been the focus-of-discussion tend to dance around a bit; the last element toggles between breaking to the next line and then snapping back. Please refer to the image below:

[image]

The reason this should be addressed is because the scope of the project has the potential of serving people from many different demographics (especially those who may need to scroll in, or out for that matter, to make the text larger or smaller). A very broad project, indeed.

How can I reach my goal highlighted in the example above? 
How can I have 4 or 5 or more (or less) **bordered** elements floated next to one another, sized proportionally using %s, WITHOUT them breaking form?

Comment: Is this happening because of rounding errors? What if you size them all at 19%? Not exactly a UX question though - more of a coding problem?

Comment: More of a css issue but I normall address situations like this using a main div and putting these smaller divs as relative

Comment: Browser zoom is crap, all versions of it, and there are no standards. I don't think it's ready for prime-time. Users are used to this fact, so don't lose your hair over it.

Comment: @Diodeus I wholeheartedly agree. However, I'm sure there is some near-foolproof work-around for this, somewhere out there...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the experimental [box model CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing) declaration to have the borders detract from the elements width instead of adding on to it. This should prevent the problem. Quirksmode has [a nice write up](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html) on it. It is supported by IE8/9 and current versions of webkit, opera and ff.

```
li {
   -webkit-box-sizing:  border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing:  border-box;
   box-sizing:  border-box;
}
```

Comment: A good solution, yes, but unfortunately IE7 will have to be a concern of mine. However, if no other likable solutions surface, I suppose IE7 users that zoom out may have to be left in the dust (groan). Thanks.

Comment: @VinnyBurgh - you may be surprised how few people are using IE7 these days. At my company (US/Europe centric) we are down to 1.6%. MS's recent decision to force upgrade IE6/7 users to 8/9 during the first half of twenty twelve should contribute to lowering them even more. It seems like with IE6 hanging on so long we would have to support IE7 for forever, but it is going to get the boot much faster. http://www.infopackets.com/news/business/microsoft/2011/20111219_microsoft_to_force_new_internet_explorer_on_users.htm

Comment: That's great news; glad to hear!

Comment: Why had I never heard of this before? Thanks for posting this! *Very* useful.

Comment: @VinnyBurgh plus users who zoom out (intentionally) are a significantly smaller subset of even IE7 users.

Comment: @BenBrocka That's probably true. It's a minor issue, sure, but I have a problem with letting little things like that go.

Comment: @VinnyBurgh I do too...unless it's IE's fault

Answer (score 4):

The basic issue here, I think, is that you're 'misusing' the width property - width is supposed to control inner boxes, not the size of outer boxes. That is, your borders are supposed to be added on to your boxes, not included in the calculated width.

The result is that you don't have many choices beyond either:

1. Using Javascript to do some fancy recalculation,
2. Seeing if you can trigger quirks mode and use the IE5 box model (NOT a good idea),
3. Replacing borders several background images in lots of stacked divs (not nice), or,
4. Floating 20% width containers, then putting width:auto divs (*not* width:100%) with borders *in* the parent floats.

I know solution 4 sounds horrible, and means non-semantic markup, but it's a common kludge and one that other developers will probably understand (too) well.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand how width works, no worries, as well as borders. However, they are both included in the calculation of sizing (just as padding and margin would be too). Your 3rd solution is one I've practice for a while now, but seems to be a bit inefficient. Perhaps this issue isn't exactly make-or-break, as a comment or two have pointed out on the original question, but it's killing the perfectionist in me.

Comment: Your 4th solution is on one I've practiced for a while now*

Answer (score 1):

This may sound horrible, but why not use a background image to create the border?

```
.box_20_percent {
   width:20%;
   float:left;
   padding:0;
   background-image:url([one_pixel_colored_image]);
   background-repeat:repeat-y; 
   background-position:right
}
```

This should leave the "border" out of the resize calculation altogether.

Comment: While this work, it's exactly how you introduced it: horrible (although I'd prefer to call it ugly, not horrible :P). Thank you for your response though!

Comment: It's true, though I'm not sure that any solution is going to be elegant if need good cross-browser support :)

Comment: I've run into this probably before, and this solution has worked pretty well (I probably shouldn't admit it, but I've also retreated to *gasp* table-layout!)

Comment: @BenD - GASP! Careful with them words around here. The downvoting pedants will beat you silly!

Answer (score 1):

If you declare the border-width and negative margin in ems instead of pixels, there is no wrapping/jumping. I realize this may be cold comfort since it would compromise your design somewhat, but it works!

Comment: Very interesting. I'd be sold if the border wouldn't resize to unquestionable sizes.

Comment: Try using "thin" instead of declaring numeric ems or pixels. The other arbitrary values are "medium" and "thick". Interesting, no?

Comment: To clarify: try margin-right: -.3em; border: thin solid #000;

Comment: Who would have thought!? Yours was a likeable solution, but mrtsherman above has me sold.

Comment: .3em on where I'll be using it in the current project is about 6px wide.

Comment: mrtsherman definitely offers the best solution, if you don't have to support older browsers!

Comment: Regarding the width of the ems, you gotta play with it. Defs not a perfect solution, but it is a solution. :)